# How can I format a string in java "012df3g4h5j6 78" => "01 23 45 67 8"

Tags: java, regex, replace, numbers, format

**I want to format a string with numbers and other characters:
Sample:**

input => output

- "012df3g4h5j6 78" => "01 23 45 67 8"
- "012df3g4h5j6 7" => "01 23 45 67"
- "012 3 45 6 78" => "01 23 45 67 8"
- "012 3 45 6" => "01 23 45 6"

**I have a solutions only for numbers:**

- "012345678" => "01 23 45 67 8"
- "01234567" => "01 23 45 67"
- "01234567" => "01 23 45 67"

regexp = "(?=[0-9]{2})(([0-9]){2})"

replacement = "$1 "

Comment: Split the string on non-numbers, then join, then use your regex.

Comment: Can you strip anything that is not a number out first, and then apply your regex?

Comment: no, i must have it in one regex :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
(\D*)(\d)(?:(\n)|(\D*)(\d)(\n?))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ6nA5/1)

Or

```
(\D*)(\d)(?:(\n|$)|(\D*)(\d)((?:\n|$)?))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ6nA5/3)

**Explanation:**
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)
`(?: … )`: Non-capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bU9dN1/1)
`|`: Alternation / OR operand [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ0iC0/1)
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)

Input:

```
012df3g4h5j6 78
012df3g4h5j6 7
012 3 45 6 78
012 3 45 6
012345678
01234567
01234567
```

Output

```
01 23 45 67 8 
01 23 45 67 
01 23 45 67 8 
01 23 45 6 
01 23 45 67 8 
01 23 45 67 
01 23 45 67
```

Comment: @anubhava thank you, i updated regex to solve that case https://regex101.com/r/mJ6nA5/3

Comment: Thanks, good update. I may be nitpicking but it leaves a trailing space in each line.

Comment: @anubhava correct, need to trim that trailing space : D

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in 2 steps:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("\\D", "").replaceAll("(\\d{2})(?!$)", "$1 ");
```

In 1st step we remove all non-digits from string and in 2nd we insert a space after every 2 digits except the last one.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is one step process:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("\\D*(\\d)(?!\\d?$)(?:\\D*(\\d))?\\D*", "$1$2 ");
```

[RegEx Demo of 1 step replacement](https://regex101.com/r/tS4mL9/5)

[Working Code Demo](http://ideone.com/tVpXZy)

Comment: i must have it in one replaceAll :(

Comment: ist it possible to chain to regex?

Comment: its not working:-http://ideone.com/Ck6Eer

can you check for the first two string

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer (without regex) would be to iterate over the string look for digits and create a new string with them grouped in twos.

```
String input = ...;
String output = "";
boolean space = false;
for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
        continue;
    }
    output += c;
    if (space) {
        output += ' ';
    }
    space = !space;
}
output = output.trim(); //To remove trailing space if present
```

If you feel that there are too many String concatenations, then you can consider using `StringBuffer`